Странное задание на позицию Angular разработчика позциция Junior | Request to API | Собеседование
Возможно, мой вопрос покажется слишком странным, но хотелось бы, чтобы вы поделились опытом, как решили вы бы данное задание.
Само задание

Используя модуль HttpModule, предоставленный Angular 2+,
напишите фрагмент кода, который будет получать второй элемент (в
возвращаемом порядке) со статусом 'pending' из API ниже.
https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/todos

Я решил задание, используя pipe -> filtr + map (можно сделать без map). Отфильтровал данные и описал, как отобразить результат.
Сегодня я получил электронное письмо, в котором утверждается, что мое решение не было правильным. Я решил уточнить, в чем именно заключается ошибка в моем решении, после чего получил ответ:

Привет! Благодарим вас за обращение к нам. Я объясню, что мы хотели
достичь с этой задачей. В вашем решении данные фильтруются на стороне
интерфейса и должны фильтроваться на стороне API. В этом задании мы
хотели проверить, как кандидат подходит к решению задачи. Мы ожидаем,
что кандидат не знаком с нашим API. В такой ситуации важным условием
является умение находить и использовать документацию. Вместо того,
чтобы загружать все результаты и фильтровать их в памяти, мы ожидаем,
что кандидат будет загружать соответствующие данные непосредственно из
указанного API.

Я смотрел на текст мейла и не понимал, что происходит ) После этого я проверил ссылку, по которой находится API, и там действительно есть документация. Но я не вижу эндпоинтов, где могу указать параметры для того, чтобы отфильтровать response. Вот ссылка: https://gorest.co.in. Там есть GraphQL, но в задании не говорится о использовании Apollo, поэтому я предположил, что здесь используется RestAPI, и нужно сконцентрироваться на базовом понимании операторов с RxJS
Мой вопрос заключается в том, как бы вы поступили в данной ситуации? Возможно, я действительно узко мыслю и что-то не понимаю. Вообще, хотелось бы узнать, как бы вы решили данную задачу?

В целом, тут стоит подходить к заданию так, чтобы заранее узнать побольше требований и уточнить какие-то вопросы до выполнения задания. Конечно, если они ищут именно Angular-разработчика и хотят проверять его скиллы - то это немного избыточно. Но скорее всего - это комплексная проверка кандидата, насколько в целом готов окунуться и неизвестный код и раскопать как с ним работать. Для тестового задания кажется, что норм.

Будь это тестовым заданием, которое дают после разговора с HR, я бы не удивился такому ответу. Но это было на этапе регистрации формы и отправки резюме. То есть у них на сайте в форме, прежде чем отправить резюме, нужно ответить на вопрос и вставить кусочек кода в инпут. Где они описали, что нужно отфильтровать ответ с API по статусу и получить второй из списка. Не было вопроса о том, как бы ты оптимизировал данное решение, не ссылки на  документациию, ничего не было. Сомневаюсь, что на этом этапе ключевым моментом было то, что нужно связаться с ними и спросить.

Как-то я смотрел видео, в котором обсуждали подобные моменты, и мне понравилось, как один специалист высказал мнение, что на данном этапе это, скорее всего, просто специально сделано для отсева кандидатов, ибо просить другого программиста тратить время на проверку каждого - это затраты.  А HR, по своему опыту скажу, в большинстве случаев не знают разницу между Java и JavaScript :)Таким образом, на проверку со стороны HR можно не рассчитывать. Вот я думаю, это просто банальная неумело придуманная причина с их стороны, чтобы отказывать кандидатам

Ну, я благодарен, что они мне дали такой глупый ответ), где даже в документации нет способа сделать то, что они просят. Просто жаль, что они такой же ответ дают и другим кандидатам. Хотя, может, я просто такой счастливчик, и моя фотография не понравилась HR xD

Если это не тестовое задание, а отсев кандидатов, то у компании довольно большие трудности с набором сотрудников. Согласен, какой-то отсев нужно делать, например, если надо найти сеньора, и не хочется тратить время на джунов. Но в данном случае, это какой-то хардкорный отсев. Я бы еще несколько раз подумал, прежде чем пойти в такую компанию

В документации все есть, ваш ответ скорее всего такой:
https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/todos?page=2&per_page=1&status=pending
Но причем тут Angular уже понять сложно.

А где в документации написано про status?

Ни где, между строк, исходя из задания и других запросов. Так сказать на опыте.

То есть вы просто угадали? Ну так наверно тоже можно, но, во-первых, попахивает раздолбайством, а во-вторых, получается, что ваше утверждение «В документации все есть» является ложным

Вы читать не умеете?
"Full search support on all fields. Ex: https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users?name=kumar"

То есть теперь оказывается, что ваш предыдущий комментарий про «Ни где» является ложным? Забавную ситуацию вы для себя создали, теперь в любом случае вы оказываетесь лжецом)

Ну и в любом случае такая документация в таком виде является дерьмом: читаем буквально предыдущую строчку про ".xml", открываем для примера todos.xml, видим там поле <user-id/>, вбиваем параметр для поиска ?user-id=777 — ой, а оно не работает! Нельзя так по-раздолбайски документацию писать

Странный вы, буквально про поле статус там не написано, Вам все не нравится...

Ого, никогда бы не подумал, что можно так сделать. Отмечу ваш ответ как решение :). Согласен, тут уже и не идет речь о Angular. Обычно, когда отправляешь резюме на позицию Angular developer, то автоматически фокусируешься на этом фреймворке и думаешь, что в этом задании нужно просто показать, что ты понимаешь, как использовать RxJS и операторы, которые он предоставляет, но точно не о том, что нужно догадаться, что это нужно сделать с помощью правильного запроса. Спасибо за ответ, теперь я буду о таких вариантах думать в будущем :)
